# Logical Error in Code Snippet?

Tags: java, logic

I was doing one of the questions of the google code jam and i got stuck at this point. The code compiles correctly but after the input of 'N', it doesn't go further. Looks like a logical error but when i dry run the code, it looks fine. What could be the issue here? The question is here https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/6254486/dashboard

```
public class Counting_Sheep
{
static int haha,digit,j;
static int arr[]=new int[11];
public static void main(String args[])throws IOException{
    BufferedReader obj=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Number of test cases");
    int t=in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter N by Bleatrix");
    int n=Integer.parseInt(obj.readLine());
    if(n==0){
        System.out.println("INSOMNIA");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    for(int i=1;i<=n+1;i++){
        haha=i*n;
        numbercalculator(haha);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<11;i++)
    System.out.println(arr[i]);
}
static void numbercalculator(int a){
    while(a>0){
        digit=a%10;
        if(digitIsUnique(digit)){
        arr[j]=digit;
        j++;
    }
    }
}
static boolean digitIsUnique(int b){
    for(int i=0;i<11;i++){
        if(b==arr[i])
        return false;
        else
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running it with a debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this not an endless loop?

```
while(a>0){
    digit=a%10;
    if(digitIsUnique(digit)){
        arr[j]=digit;
        j++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeaup. Got the issue. Its this only. had to do while digit>0 and after finding the remainder divide the digit by 10